# Bulk Import Leads From SQL Table and store leads id back into table

Tags: apex, batch, integration, bulk-api

I need to bulk import leads from sql server table, get back the newly created leadid and store them back on sql table.
I read documentation on salesforce bulk api.
Salesforce returns a response with data such as the following:

```
"Id","Success","Created","Error"
"003x0000004ouM4AAI","true","true",""
"003x0000004ouM5AAI","true","true",""
```

Does that means i need to store local id in salesfoce and after bulk job is completed fetch the records and store the leads id in sql server or their is some better approach please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  any ETL Tool for Migrating records from Sql Server.into Salesforce. ETL tool will push leadid values back to Database after every successful sync.

You can have a primary key in Sql Server and also another field in database to store the leadid from Salesforce.

You can Go with either Informatica or DBSync. Comparatively DBSync is cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Any ETL tool is capable integrating data between multiple end points. For importing leads from a database into Salesforce, you can make a small change into your source table by adding a small column called as “SFID” or “salesforce_Ids” or any naming convention of your choice.  Upon every sync that happens between the database and Salesforce, this column inturn is used to store SF record IDs everytime a new record is created / updated in SF, thereby establishing a link between every row of your SQL Server table with that of the Salesforce Lead record inturn Salesforce Lead object with that of the SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0):

I used Bulk API in mulesoft to load data from SQL to salesforce and write back salesforce Id to SQL source table. Fully automated.

Let me know if you need help.

Thanks
Pradeep